# I found a table with these values and want to know what hashing function this is similar to

Tags: hash, hash-function

```
INSERT INTO `car_user` 
    (`id`, `name`, `email`, `address`, `phone`, `password`, `role`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `deleted_at`) 
VALUES
    (1, 'Henry', 'henry@yahoo.com', 'Allgatan 20, Malmo, Sweden', '02939394', '$2y$10$e5d5kN9PPq1Ac.0DHwZPx.YLqNwE.xaF56KYuVv4OTWpQyuej4Pva', 1, '2018-03-22 23:00:00', '2018-04-03 21:03:14', NULL),
    (2, 'Grace', 'grace@yahoo.com', 'Hill View Crescent 30, New York', '0737282837', '$2y$10$qlBXI0o0wwVoFFLVh48w5.kTsjr9WZlRa1j4R8aonsKpccMpYAcE6', 3, '2018-04-02 23:57:27', '2018-04-02 23:57:27', NULL),
    (3, 'Kayode Johnson ', 'kayodejohnson@gmail.com', NULL, NULL, '$2y$10$2JeVt3GF484wEcjgRCusSO4zroeWe/iq1qjb.KoQw616YbCp8Bgg.', 3, '2018-04-30 23:34:15', '2018-04-30 23:34:15', NULL);
```

any idea of which hashing this is familiar too because every time I create a new user with md5 it says wrong user name and password

Comment: I really hope this is not real personal information.

Comment: no it isnt at all

Answer (score 0):

These are post-bugfix PHP crypt_blowfish hashes.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt#Versioning_history